# creating a chart.js scatter graph with variables for data

Tags: javascript, chart.js, scatter-plot

I am writing a program that will eventually generate a graph based on user input. so I've created a proof of concept that should click a button and make a chart.js scatter graph my issue is that the data is not included for some reason not sure why.

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Test1</title>

<script src="Chart.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button onmousedown="addData()"></button>

<script>
function addData(){
    ABC=[[1,2,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]];
    chart(ABC);
}



function chart(array)
{
    for (counter = 0; counter < array.length; counter++) 
    {
        var entery = {x: array[counter][0], y: array[counter][3]};
        storage.push(entery);
    }

    document.write('<canvas id="lineChart" height="200" width="450"></canvas>');    


    const chart=document.getElementById("lineChart");
    console.log(chart)
    var myChart = new Chart(chart, {
        type: 'scatter',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                "fill":false,
                pointRadius: 10,
                label: 'Scatter Dataset',
                data: storage        
                }]

        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: 'linear',
                }]
            }
        }
    });

}
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

I cannot work out why the data is not included any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some issues with setting up your code:

1. You have not defined `storage` array
2. `console.log(chart)` throws an error, you have to comment that line out or remove it
3. The elements in your ABC array does not have 4 elements(arrays are 0 indexed and
   your last index will be 2 not 3)
   So this line `var entery = {x: array[counter][0], y: array[counter][3]};` should be changed to `var entery = {x: array[counter][0], y: array[counter][2]};`

So, your code should look like this:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Test1</title>
    <script src="Chart.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="addData();">Test</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function addData(){
            ABC=[[1,2,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]];
            chart(ABC);
        }


        function chart(array)
        {
            var storage = [];
            for (counter = 0; counter < array.length; counter++) 
            {
                var entery = {x: array[counter][0], y: array[counter][2]};
                storage.push(entery);
            }

            document.write('<canvas id="lineChart" height="200" width="450"></canvas>');    

            const chart = document.getElementById("lineChart");
            //console.log(chart)
            var myChart = new Chart(chart, {
                type: 'scatter',
                data: {
                    datasets: [{
                        "fill":false,
                        pointRadius: 10,
                        label: 'Scatter Dataset',
                        data: storage        
                        }]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            type: 'linear',
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8nbp3L0f/1/) you can find a working copy of the chart.